# Is this a valid equation for determining certificate lifetimes in a PKI infrastructure?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I have an intuitive sense of how certificate lifetimes should work in a PKI infrastructure, but I don't consider myself an expert in this field so I would like someone to validate or critique my assumptions:

The "leaves" on a PKI hierarchy are the certificates issued by a CA. The maximum lifetime of one such certificate is equivalent to:

```
renewal interval          + renewal period           = certificate lifetime
(renew yearly, i.e. 1 yr) + (1-month renewal period) = 13 month lifetime
```

An intermediate/issuing CA's cert's lifetime follows the same pattern, *plus* the maximum lifetime of a cert it can issue:

```
renewal interval + renewal period + child lifetime = certificate lifetime
2 years          + 1 month        + 13 months      = 3 year, 2 month lifetime
```

The last step "recurses" up the PKI hierarchy through any more intermediate CA tiers until you get to the root cert.

This means, necessarily, a CA's cert must always have a lifetime longer than the certs it issues.

---

Context: [Apple's Announcement](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/02/20/apple_shorter_cert_lifetime/) about 13-month maximum cert lifetimes starting September 1st 2020 must therefore only apply to leaf certs, and not to certs issued to intermediate or root CAs.

Comment: A CA's certificate can renew end-entity certificates many times.  Your equation for intermediate/issuing CA's cert lifetime therefore doesn't really work.

Comment: Your post has little sense. Where did you get 1mo renewal period? One rule that is relevant and valid: issued certificate MUST NOT exceed the validity of issuer certificate. Renewal period is not standartized anywhere and is up to particular CA practices.

Comment: @Crypt32 Right, I'm aware of the rule you mention. All of the periods I've listed as examples are arbitrary, but not unrealistic (I don't think).

Comment: It is hard do judge them in abstract, outside of particular example. Apple's announcement is a bit different story and doesn't tell anything about renewal period. Often (not always), CA certs are valid for longer periods than end entity certificates, that's correct.

Comment: @garethTheRed My point there is that if the CA is issuing 13-month certs, it can do so only up until 13 months prior to _it's own_ cert's expiration.

Comment: Microsoft CAs will not issue a certificate that expires after the CA's certificate expires.  But that's simply a design decision.  There is nothing stopping a CA issuing a cert that will outlive the CA cert.  However, the chain will not validate when the CA expires, until the CA certificate is renewed (same subject & keys, different expiry date).

Comment: You may wish to read NIST SP 800-57 for some guidance in this area.